# save pdf problem with Silverlight from Windows Azure

Tags: silverlight, azure-storage

Hi I am using http://silverlightpdf.codeplex.com/ code to print pdf from my silverlight application hosted in Windows Azure.

I am able to save the pdf from local/development pc, but when I try save the pdf from Azure Server, it is giving following error.

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; GTB7.0; EasyBits GO v1.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; OfficeLiveConnector.1.5; OfficeLivePatch.1.3; FDM)
Timestamp: Fri, 19 Aug 2011 04:24:34 UTC

Message: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application The remote server returned an error: NotFound.   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at InspirED.StudentHome.View.NotesTab.Notes.PrintGetResponse(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c_*DisplayClassd.b*_b(Object state2)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://mystorageaccount.cloudapp.net/somappname.studenttestpage.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you did not post any code I can only guess what the problem is. But according to [this](http://www.windowsazure4j.org/learn/labs/lab1_storage_blobs/) page it could be due to.

> When a container is deleted, a container with the same name cannot be created for at least 30 seconds; the container may not be available for more than 30 seconds if the service is still processing the request. While the container is being deleted, attempts to create a container of the same name will fail with status code 409 (Conflict), with the service returning additional error information indicating that the container is being deleted. All other operations, including operations on any blobs under the container, will fail with status code 404 (Not Found) while the container is being deleted.

If not, please post a sample of your code.